# How to find a string in Electron webview tag?

Tags: webview, node-webkit, electron

i am trying to get find a string in electron webview tag. 
    In node-webkit we have api like webview.find('string',callback);
    but i couldn't find any api in electron webview tag. If you have any 
    idea, share your idea ,comments are appreciated. if iam in wrong path
    please correct me Thanks.

Comment: Could you give us some sample code by any chance? I am not familiar with electron and don't know how to start debugging to find a solution.

Comment: @Ewald ,In chrome webview tag we have api to find a string link give below https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-find , but in Electron they are writing webview tag api with compatible to electron engine http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.35.0/api/web-view-tag/ so here i dont find any find function , might be they release this feature in future version

Comment: I see what you mean, I don't have a clean solution for you unfortunately.